# creating a file and all parent directories

Tags: android, file, io

is there a method that allows in Android 2.1 to create a new file and, if relative directories do not exist, to create them too?
make me know, 'cause this snippet does not work:

```
    static String separator = File.separator;
public static final String DIRECTORYBIGLIETTI = "C:" + separator + "Users" + separator + "7-Spode" + separator + "Documents" + separator + "Android" + separator + "HUVWSZE"; ///sdcard/.SpodeApps/HUVWSZE/
public static final String FILEBIGLIETTI = DIRECTORYBIGLIETTI.concat(separator + "lista.txt");

File cartellainputoutput = new File(DIRECTORYBIGLIETTI);
        if(!cartellainputoutput.exists())
        {
            cartellainputoutput.mkdirs();
        }
        File fileinputoutput = new File(FILEBIGLIETTI);
        if(!fileinputoutput.exists())
            try {
                fileinputoutput.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

may i ask to the admin for upgrading this web site's graphics? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `mkdirs()` to create the directories, and then create the file.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make this clear, you cannot use Windows-like file paths (such as  `C:\Users\7-Spode\Documents\Android\HUVWSZE`) in Android, you have to use Linux-like file paths (like `/data/my.android.application/data_directory/file` or `/sdcard/directory/file`.

Also, you should use methods such as [`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) (for internal storage) and [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) (for external storage, e.g. SD cards) to get those directories, and from there you can just create a regular `File` object and handle it from there.

Example (with internal storage):

```
File dir = getFilesDir(); // Returns a directory exclusively for this app.
File file = new File(dir, "directory/file");
file.mkdirs();
file.createNewFile();
```

Also note that when working with external storage, you should always check if external storage is unavailable (for instance if SD card has been removed, or the device is connected 
 to a computer), using [`getExternalStorageState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29).

For more information about how to use internal and external storage in Android, read [this nifty article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: this is right. just to complete the answer... the graphics are fine! :)